# Convert from Castle Windsor to Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, castle-windsor, autofac

I need to use property injection on filters and unfortunately Castle doesn't support it. So I have to change my IoC to Autofac. However I'm having problems doing so.

How can I change the following code to use Autofac.

```
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ILogService>()
                .ImplementedBy<LogService>()
                .LifeStyle.Singleton,

            Component.For(typeof(IDatabaseFactory<>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(DatabaseFactory<>))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest(),

            Component.For(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(UnitOfWork<>))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest(),

            Types.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IHttpController>()
                .LifestyleTransient(),

            Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyServer.DAL")
                .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest(),

            Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyServer.Service")
                .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest()
            );
```

Also, using Castle, I code dispose of the container in Global.asax. Does Autofac allow for container disposal?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Autofac, you need to use a ContainerBuilder object to register your types and build the container from this object.

So, first you need to do something like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
```

then, you can use the builder to register the types depending on the life time that you want (I will show you how to register Singleton and Generic types, and you can refer to the [documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/register/index.html) to see how to do other types like scanning the assembly for types etc...

i. For Singleton, you can use the following:

```
// Register instances of objects you create...
var output = new StringWriter();
builder.RegisterInstance(output).As<TextWriter>();
```

ii. For Generics implementations, you can use something like the following:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

finally, you need to Build the container as follows:

```
// Build the container to finalize registrations
// and prepare for object resolution.
var container = builder.Build();
```

- Also, in the documentation you can find a section that shows how you can do property [injection](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#property-injection). 
  however, if you want to do that for Web API action filters, you need to know that when filter instances are first created in Web API they are cached, so Autofac has to resolve the property injection using the root lifetime scope, not the request lifetime scope. and you may need to use `actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IYourService);`

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659108/webapi-autofac-system-web-http-filters-actionfilterattribute-instance-per-requ) for more details